# Delete Rows using Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete data from 4 table using single query.

```
delete e1,e2,e3,e4 FROM sas.RolesInMenuOperations as e1 INNER JOIN
sas.RolesMenus as e2 ON e1.RoleMenuId = e2.Id INNER JOIN
sas.RolesInModules as e3 ON e2.RolesInModulesId = e3.Id INNER JOIN
sas.Roles as e4 ON e3.RoleId = e4.Id
where e4.Id=5
```

This is what I have done so far. I was refering [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/275195/SQL-DELETE-Query-with-INNER-JOIN) link
Is it possible to delete data from 4 table using Joins.
How to achieve this or I want to write 4 different queries?

Though this query works properly

```
delete e1 FROM sas.RolesInMenuOperations as e1 INNER JOIN
sas.RolesMenus as e2 ON e1.RoleMenuId = e2.Id INNER JOIN
sas.RolesInModules as e3 ON e2.RolesInModulesId = e3.Id INNER JOIN
sas.Roles as e4 ON e3.RoleId = e4.Id
where Roles.Id=5
```

Comment: this will work on `MySQL` but not on `SQL Server`.

Comment: Is any another way around for doing this?

Comment: @JW: Deleting from multiple tables in SQL Server would require multiple queries then, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not delete multiple table data using a single query in SQL Server.
Best concept is to give FK in relative table and use **ON DELETE CASCADE** or use individual queries to delete from multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

So you are looking for MS SQL syntax ?
Something liek this works:

```
DELETE table 
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table_b b on b.id = a.id
WHERE [my filter condition]
```

So if you want to delete more tables rows you need to create more statements and fire them I think.